# How to find missing brace in .cpp / search within comments?

Tags: search, c++

File has one fewer "}" than "{", however all seem matched.

Therefore, it is probably in a comment.

**How do I search within a comment or otherwise find the missing brace?**

Comment: What text editor are you using?

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using a text editor such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which gives you syntax highlighting and parenthesis matching. Navigate to each bracket/parenthesis/brace, and it will highlight the matching one. This will help you find the missing character.

Answer (score 2):

A simple trick to find unbalanced braces and parentheses in C and C++ files is to run [GNU indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) across them.

Throw away the output and only look at the warnings and errors produced, they will show unbalanced braces and parentheses also in dead code.

To do this across a source tree I use it like

```
find . -name "*.[ch]*"|xargs -n1 indent -st >/dev/null
```